# Bash script to kill all programs and restart them after a minute

Tags: linux, bash, server

I need to write a **bash** script to kill all programs running on a  Linux server and then restarting them, preferably after a minute.

I am new to bash scripting. Please help.

Comment: All programs? Why not just reboot?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please edit your post and include what you have tried so far.

Comment: be careful not to kill programs that are needed for the operation of your linux OS..also when restarting your programs you will need to know what programming language your programs are created with so that you can restart them successfully

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is to write a script that kills your services. Then a second script that launches them. Set your crontab to run the first script on minute n, then second script at n+1. That should clear the existing programs and launch them after one minute.

Comment: Most services would have a recommended way to shut them down, or even a crontab-line example. @user3270763 You might try reading the docs for each service that is interesting to you; for each additional doc/service, the probability approaches 100% that at least one of them will give you the "right" answer for your needs, perhaps a better one that you'll find here!

Answer (score 1):

Killing ALL programs would be...not good...as in system crash probably. But if you were so inclined:

```
#!/bin/bash

processes=`ps aux -A --no-heading | grep -v "NameOfThisScript" | awk '{print $2}'`

for i in $processes; do
    sudo kill -9 $i
done
```

Ooops, forgot the part about restarting them...

Comment: At that point, why not `telinit 1`, followed by `telinit 5`? ;-) (Also, I would *never* use `-9` in such a capricious way.)

Comment: I agree about th `-9` but the OP said he wanted to kill **ALL** programs. Logically this would include ones that would otherwise be blocked.

Comment: One should only use `-9` for misbehaving programs, not all. It's better to send a term signal, then sleep for a few seconds, then `kill -9`; that gives programs the chance to clean up and end normally, before you kill them abruptly.